# Adding active state to css based horizontal menu not shoing the sub menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I have modified linear menu [show in the example](http://www.lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu/) as per my needs so far i had no issue except one i am not able to find a way to show the menus related to particular page on page load or in other words i want to add an active state to `li` & based on that show thouse sub menus for it parent menu.

Suppose if user click on the `About Us` link then it should show menus for this by default.

Here is my example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ym5PJ/)

My question my confuse the reader, I simple need to show menu for particular page on page load what change do i need to make to css so that i can show sub menu with the help of jquery of may be just with css only.

I tried few thing but ended up messing the whole..

Comment: I think you misunderstand the :active selector. That is a state only existing while the mouse button is held down. If you want a state that affects the actual menu-point, then you are better of making a class for this state.

Comment: @sven, Agree with you but i thing it should be possible to do it with jquery, for example when i generate the menu in asp.net i can check if pageid & if it is the same i can add a show then particular menu, problem for me now is i am not able to figure out how i can show particular sub menu based using css once   i figure that out then i can use jquery to show the submenu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add an .active class to the list element that is the current page being shown rather than the sub-menu unordered list (since semantically, it's the page being active, not its submenu). So in your markup, you'd have 
    `<li class="active"><span class="dir"><a href="ultimate.linear-active.html">About Us</a></span> ....` and in your stylesheet add

```
li.active > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

​
Then you can style the current page tab accordingly, using `li.active`.

Comment: Exactly what i was trying to do...I was almost going the same excpet i was adding `class=active` to `ul` of sub menu. thanks..